# Can't select a value from list

Tags: python, list

I have this code:

```
import os
import pprint 
print("Hello")
ModList = os.listdir("C:/Users/Dat/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/mods")
print ("The current mods you have installed are:\n")
pprint.pprint(ModList)
DisableNumber = input("To disable a mod, type it's number in the list.\n")
int (DisableNumber)
FileToDisable = ModList[DisableNumber]
print (FileToDisable)
```

It's supposed to list the files in a directory, print the list, ask the user to input a number, and it renames the filename with that index in the list. However, when I run this, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dat\Desktop\Python\ModDisabler.py", line 9, in <module>
FileToDisable = ModList[DisableNumber]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

What is the cause of this error? I think it's because the int(DisableNumber) is not working, but I can't seem to find out why for the life of me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, this part isn't working, because you didn't save the result of the conversion and the modification doesn't occur in-place:

```
int(DisableNumber)
```

Try this instead:

```
DisableNumber = int(input("To disable a mod, type it's number in the list.\n"))
```

Notice that `input()` returns a string that must be explicitly converted to an `int`, if it contains an integer value that you intend to use as a number - for example, as an array index. Now that `DisableNumber` is an integer, this line will work:

```
FileToDisable = ModList[DisableNumber]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `int(DisableNumber)` with `DisableNumber = int(DisableNumber)`

Comment: The reason this is necessary is that `int(DisableNumber)` does not change the variable in place, but *returns* an integer from whatever was in `DisableNumber`.